# Routing issues with Codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter, routes

In my routes.php file I have the following codes:

```
$route['admin/login'] = 'admin/login/index';
    $route['admin/add_client'] = 'admin/add_client/index';

    $route['(:any)'] = function ($val){
    require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB.php' );
    $db =& DB();
    $db->select('url');
    $db->from('interior_form');
    $db->where('url',$val);
    $query = $db->get()->row();
    $db->close();
    if(sizeof($query)>0):

        return 'home';
    else:
         return "404_override";
    endif;
```

The issue that I am facing here is whenever I put www.xyz.com/admin/login , it goes to the home page first then again if I write www.xyz.com/admin/login in the same browser, only then it goes to the admin login page.It does not go to the admin login page on the very first instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$route['admin/login'] = 'admin/login/index';
$route['admin/add_client'] = 'admin/add_client/index';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
```

In your home controller, there you handle which request is 404 and which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit your Rout file.first of all come out from that file.

and you can do this.....

In admin controller page create a function called index.in that function you load your login page.
whenever you type www.xyz.com/admin then load the admin login page.

note:-
 Which controller page contains index function,first that index function is load when call that controller, because of index function is first priority compare to other functions in all controllers page.

Comment: admin is the folder, login is the page and index is the function in my case.($route['admin/login'] = 'admin/login/index';)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this simple code for set up rout as bellow.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Adminlogin';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```